# NetUtils java library - how to make it work?

Tags: java

I'm trying for a while to use a library in java that I found a few months ago for edit packets.
The library is "like" jnetpcap but much richer, and most important seems to be newer and less buggy...
Here is the open source homepage of the project:
https://code.google.com/p/netutils/downloads/detail?name=netutils_toturial.pdf&can=2&q=
In the manual the person who wrote this library said we need to use "libnet.lib" and "netutils.dll" files.
I'm not really sure how to make it work, it seems to have a problam with the "netutils.dll" when trying to run a simple code.
Hope to get an answer from someone. Thanks a-lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the pdf documentation:

> The java library calls C code using java JNI (Java Native Interface).
>
> The C code is compiled into two shared libraries (Linux) or dll’s
>   (Windows). The dynamic libraries should be placed in the java
>   java.library.path (path where the JVM searches for dynamic libraries).
>
> ```
> There are two options for placing the libraries:
>
> 1. Putting the libraries in one of the default path’s.
>
> 2. Put the library anywhere and add the path to the java.library.path as shown:
>    java -Djava.library.path=place.....
> ```

Have you tried any of these options?

For point 1 you can use the following code, as reported in the dock to detect which is your java.library.path:

```
public class ShowJavaLibraryPath {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
         System.out.println(System.getProperty(”java.library.path”));
    }
}
```

If you prefer the point 2, just add the `.dll` where you prefer and add the option `-Djava.library.path=folder_you_choose` to the Run Configuration arguments.

Comment: As I wrote before, I don't really know what files I should add to the defult folder. I really have no idia what is the file `netutils.dll` if u can find me the file i'll be thankfull.